# How to get a Json from the request body and insert it in a spring boot relationship column?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am learning spring boot and am trying to send a Json in request body and insert its values in a table that has a relationship. I have a `pets` table and a `friends` table. A pet can have many friends(other pets). The basic idea is that when I click a `friend me` button on another pet's profile, it sends a json object which contains my `pet_id` and `friend_id` so that I can query using something like `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE pet_id = 123` to get a list of friends for my pet with id 123.

Here is my Pet.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pets")
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "pet_id", nullable = false)
    private int petId;

    @Column(name = "pet_name", nullable = false)
    private String petName;

    @Column(name = "species", nullable = false)
    private String species;

    @Column(name = "sex", nullable = false)
    private String sex;

    @Column(name = "breed", nullable = false)
    private String breed;

    @Column(name = "age", nullable = false)
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "pet_description", nullable = false)
    private String petDescription;

    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private String userId;


    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foreign_key_column", referencedColumnName = "pet_id")
    private List<Friend> friendsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Pet() {
    }

    public Pet(int petId, String petName, String species, String sex, String breed, int age, String petDescription, String userId) {
        this.petId = petId;
        this.petName = petName;
        this.species = species;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.age = age;
        this.petDescription = petDescription;
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    public List<Friend> getFriendsList() {
        return friendsList;
    }
```

Here is my Friend.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "friends")
public class Friend {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "pet_friend_uid", nullable = false)
    private int petFriendUid;

    @Column(name = "friend_id")
    private int friendId;


    public Friend() {

    }

    public Friend(int friendId) {
        this.friendId = friendId;
    }

    public int getFriendId() {
        return friendId;
    }

    public int getPetFriendUid() {
        return petFriendUid;
    }

}
```

And my FriendController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/friendslist")
public class FriendController {

    public FriendService friendService;

    public FriendController(FriendService friendService) {
        this.friendService = friendService;
    }

    //build create new Friend API
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Friend> saveFriend(@RequestBody Friend friend) {
        ResponseEntity<Friend> newFriend = new ResponseEntity<Friend>(friendService.saveFriend(friend), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        return newFriend;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Friend> getAllFriends() {
        return friendService.getAllFriends();
    }

}
```

I am having a really hard time understanding how can I send the Json from, let's say postman, with a post request like such

```
{
    "friendId": 111,
    "foreign_key_column": 3
}
```

Currently, if I send the above json from postman, only the `friendId` gets posted on the table but the `foreign_key_column` which references the parent table remains null. Does the `foreign_key_column` value need to be sent as a pathvariable? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="friendsList")                                                                                                                               Pet Pet; //getter setter` in  `Friend` entity

Comment: I do not want it to be a bidirectional relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses [jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) to map JSON string to the Request body define in the API. Jackson maps json string by the object variable `names, getters and setters`. Try doing the following change:

**Friend.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "friends")
public class Friend {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "pet_friend_uid", nullable = false)
    private int petFriendUid;

    @Column(name = "friend_id")
    private int friendId;


    public int getPetFriendUid() {
        return petFriendUid;
    }

    public void setPetFriendUid(int petFriendUid) {
        this.petFriendUid = petFriendUid;
    }

    public int getFriendId() {
        return friendId;
    }

    public void setFriendId(int friendId) {
        this.friendId = friendId;
    }
}
```

Send the below json string from postman:

```
{
        "friendId": 111,
        "petFriendUid": 3
}
```

Comment: Hello, petFriendUid is only there as a unique id for the friends table and is auto generated. I need to insert value from Json and insert that value in the joincolumn called foreign_key_column.

Comment: Where are you expecting the foreign_key_column to be saved? Also foreign_key_column will only come in the api if you have a mapping variable in the Java class

Comment: I plan to save foreign_key_column in the friends table. I was just able to accomplish this by adding variable and naming it with the same column name as defined in the parent's joincolumn name. idk if this is the best approach but it accomplishes the task for now.

Comment: That's great. If you have a column for foreign key it can be used to back track the parent entity.

Comment: that's a bidirectional relationship yes? with many to one relationship on the child entitiy?

Comment: Yes, it is a bidirectional relationship.